# Unable to create new site with gatsby

Tags: reactjs, npm, windows-10, gatsby

I'm not able to create new site with gatsby.

I have followed several issues with some similarity nothing seems to work.

re-installed node and required visual-studio build tools via visual-studio installer(2019).

environment:

OS: Windows 10 64 bit

Node: 12.18.0

npm: 6.14.4

gatsby CLI: 2.12.45

1.when I first try to generate a new site using  Gatsby-CLI I get the following error:-
[image]

2. Then I move into project folder and npm install I get the following error:-
   [image]

Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: What command are you running?

Comment: This looks more like an issue with NPM, not Gatsby, and the second screenshot shows as much.

Comment: Ok. But do you have any suggestions regarding the fix? @coreyward

Comment: 1. gatsby new site-name starter-url  2. npm install @FerranBuireu